# php how to check if key in array is unique

Tags: php, regex

I have this function for parsing arguments:

```
function arguments($argv) {
    $_ARG = array();
    foreach ($argv as $arg) {
        if (ereg('--([^=]+)=(.*)', $arg, $reg)) {
            $_ARG[$reg[1]] = $reg[2];
        } elseif (ereg('--([a-zA-Z0-0\-]*)', $arg, $reg)) {
            $_ARG[$reg[1]] = 'true';
        } elseif (ereg('-([a-zA-Z0-9])', $arg, $reg)) {
            $_ARG[$reg[1]] = 'true';
        } elseif (ereg('([a-zA-Z0-0\-]*)', $arg, $reg)) {
            $_ARG[$reg[1]] = 'true';
        }
    }
    return $_ARG;
}
```

After `var_dump()` I get something like this:

```
array(4) {
  ["xqr"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["query"]=>
  string(60) "Some string..."
 ["input"]=>
 string(12) "input03.txt"
 ["n"]=>
 string(4) "true"
}
```

My problem is, that I am not able to detect duplicates in parsed arguments. For example `php name.php  --query='Some string...'  --input=input03.txt  -n -n` or `php name.php  --query='Some string...'  --input=input03.txt  n n`. Both inputs are invalid there can be just one `-n` and can't be `n`.
Please could you help me how to handle it? Thank you

Comment: ereg function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0

Comment: It is not clear to me if you are try to detect duplicate `keys` or duplicate `values` , could you edit your post and explain a little more clearly cheers.

Comment: @Martin Problem is that in array it is saved just one time. Because if there is passed `-n -n` it is saved just one time to array as `["n"]=>string(4) "true"` so I don't know how to find duplicates then.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand it correct you need it for argument check provided in the command line.

I would not recommend to write/invent your own function again. Use the [getopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)  function.

It is very powerful and you can safe time!